# System library cannot be found

Tags: r, rstudio

I recently updated my Rstudio to version 3.6.2 and now my system cannot find the stats package in the
system library even though I can see it in my downloaded packages.
library(stats)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Comment: What exactly did you run? Note that R and RStudio are two different pieces of software. The latest version of RStudio is like 1.4 and the latest version of R is 4.0.4. Did you intentionally download an older version of R?

Comment: I downloaded RSTUDIO 1.4.1106 from https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/

Comment: My R Version:[Default] [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.2

Comment: Is there a reason for not installing v4.0.4?

Comment: Not a reason for not installing, I just do not know how to install it.

Comment: I am attempting to download it. Are you saying this will resolve the issue?

Comment: My new R Version: [Default] [64-bit] C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.4

Comment: I receive the same error as before:

Comment: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Comment: what does `.lipPaths()` say?

Comment: cannot find the function ".lipPaths"

Comment: .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Users/micha/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/4.0"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/library"

Comment: Well I resolved the issue. After installing R you must set a new environment path for RStudio to find the modules to successfully download the stats library.

Comment: Sys.setenv(PATH="/usr/bin;C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.4/bin/x64")

Comment: Can this process  be automated automatically upon opening an RStudio program without having to set a new environment variable per session? Otherwise, the command to set it must be run every new session.